# getColumnMeta() doesn’t return name of columns

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with `getColumnMeta()` in PDO: it doesn't return the names of the columns, it just returns an `Array`.

Here is my code:

```
include("connexion.php");
if (isset($_POST['exporter'])) {
    // Liste les données de la table
    $query = $connexion->query("select * from observation");

    header("Content-Type: application/csv-tab-delimited-table");
    header("Content-disposition:filename=valeur_quotidienne_avec_flag.csv");

    if ($query->rowCount() != 0) {
        // titre des colonnes
        $fields = $query->columnCount();
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $fields) {
            echo $query->getColumnMeta($i, $connexion).";";
            $i++;
        }

        echo "\n";

        // données de la table
        while ($arrSelect = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            foreach ($arrSelect as $elem) {
                echo "$elem;";
            }
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s because, as per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php), it doesn’t return just column names.

You seem to be looking for the `name` part:

```
echo $query->getColumnMeta($i, $connexion)['name'], ';';
```

The `$connexion` parameter also shouldn’t be there.